# how to upload file in alamofire in multiformData?

Tags: android, swift, alamofire, multipartform-data

I need to upload an image with multipart/form-data i have tried :

```
 static func uploadFile(image: UIImage?, parameters:Parameter,onResponse:@escaping(_ result:Parameter)-> (),onFailure:@escaping(_ error:Error)->()){
        
        let url = "ip address"
        let imageData = image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.7)
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Authorization": TOKEN!
        ]
  
        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
      
            multipartFormData.append("\(parameters.toJSON())".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: "entity")
    
            if let data = imageData{
                multipartFormData.append(data, withName: "mp3")
            }
            
        }, usingThreshold: UInt64.init(), to: url, method: .post, headers: getHeaders()) { (result) in
            
            switch result{
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    print("Succesfully uploaded",response.error)
                    if let err = response.error{
                        return
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error in upload: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        
    }
```

I need to send an entity model and the Image. but I have to send the image as a formData, not in body.

note : sending image with a "file" key and class with "entity" key

i can not solve it in swift side ....

errors :

```
Succesfully uploaded Optional(Alamofire.AFError.responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.})))
```

Comment: You’re calling neither `onResponse` nor `onFailure`. Did you remove that in an attempt to simplify your code snippets? Or are you really not calling these closures? Is the problem that the network request is not succeeding or that you just didn’t call the closures.

Comment: Finally, if you’re not 100% sure that the request is correct, I’d suggest tools like [Charles](https://charlesproxy.com) or [WireShark](https://wireshark.org) to observe the request and make sure it’s well-formed. E.g. the string interpolation of `parameters.toJSON()` could easily cause a problem if, for example, if `toJSON` already returned a `Data`. We can’t comment on that without seeing the method signature of `toJSON`...

Comment: thank you Rob for answering me. i put my console content in my post.cheek it but not a clear data in it. i have case .success and case . failure is't that correct ? the network request is succeded.

Comment: let me explain more to you. the server-side wants me a class with key name "entity" in the body request and the image with the key named: "file". Done. how do you do it?

Comment: in android adding MultipartFile and multipart-parameter is two separated command.but in swift all I have is multipartFormData for appending file and parameter.why?

Comment: you know the problem is image is going in body request which is totally incorrect

Comment: That Alamofire.AFError.responseSerializationFailed error is telling you that the server responded with something that wasn't JSON. So you should see what it said (as your server likely threw a 500 error and might show you some description of what went wrong) by looking at `response.data`.

Comment: “you know the problem is image is going in body request which is totally incorrect” ... no, when building multipart requests, the image generally _does_ go in the body of the request (that's the whole point of multipart request, so you can put it in the body). It could be because you're not supplying the `mimeType` parameters. It could be that potential `toJSON` issue. Again, I'd suggest you watch the Android request via Charles/WireShark and do it again via iOS and compare. Eliminate the guesswork.

Comment: “the server-side wants me a class with key name ‘entity’ in the body request and the image with the key named: ‘file’. Done. how do you do it?” ... No, they're generally just two parts of the same body, one is a file, one is a string or JSON component. You've got the right basic API, but I'm wagering that either it's confused by the lack of mime types (because you didn't supply that parameter to `append`) or that the JSON is not well formed. It's hard to say on the basis of what you've provided, but perhaps the text of the response from the server will help. Or compare in Charles/Wireshark.

Comment: ouhhhh Finally... I had two problem. 1. appending file with key and fileName is correct i was forgotten fileName. 2.parameter.ToJson() is incorrect. ToJsonString() is correct. rob post these tips I'll vote you up. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read comments first.

do not forget to add fileName even if you set your fileName one step before file uploading.

try to use ToJsonString() instead of using ToJson()